# Replace multiple spaces with one space in a string

Tags: c++, string, replace

How would I do something in `c++` similar to the following code:

```
//Lang: Java
string.replaceAll("  ", " ");
```

This code-snippet would replace all multiple spaces in a string with a single space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interview Question : Trim multiple consecutive spaces from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561138/interview-question-trim-multiple-consecutive-spaces-from-a-string)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
bool BothAreSpaces(char lhs, char rhs) { return (lhs == rhs) && (lhs == ' '); }

std::string::iterator new_end = std::unique(str.begin(), str.end(), BothAreSpaces);
str.erase(new_end, str.end());
```

How this works.  The [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) has two forms.  The first form goes through a range and removes adjacent duplicates.  So the string "abbaaabbbb" becomes "abab".  The second form, which I used, takes a predicate which should take two elements and return true if they should be considered duplicates.  The function I wrote, `BothAreSpaces`, serves this purpose.  It determines exactly what it's name implies, that both of it's parameters are spaces.  So when combined with `std::unique`, duplicate adjacent spaces are removed.

Just like [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), `std::unique` doesn't actually make the container smaller, it just moves elements at the end closer to the beginning.  It returns an iterator to the new end of range so you can use that to call the [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) function, which is a member function of the string class.

Breaking it down, the erase function takes two parameters, a begin and an end iterator for a range to erase.  For it's first parameter I'm passing the return value of `std::unique`, because that's where I want to start erasing.  For it's second parameter, I am passing the string's end iterator.

Comment: Cool, never seen this before. +1

Comment: @Seth: Neither have I, it just came to me suddenly.

Comment: You could even do `template<char Remove> bool BothAre(char lhs, char rhs) { return lhs == rhs && lhs == Remove; }` then `str.erase(std::unique(str.begin(), str.end(), BothAre<' '>), str.end());` to make it a tiny bit generic and usable for other characters too

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Can you explain how this works? I don't quite understand

Comment: @user386911 `std::unique` moves all consecutive duplicate characters in between the two iterators it receives to the end iterator, so that all the characters end up at the end of the string. It then returns the iterator to the beginning of all the characters it moved to the end of the string, and you pass that iterator to `str.erase` which takes two iterators and removes all the characters between them. tl;dr: all the duplicate spaces end up at the end of the string via `unique`, then `erase` removes them.

Comment: Wouldn’t I have to pass both the lhs and rhs to BothAreSpaces? And downs .erase take in a string not a bool?

Comment: @user386911 you're passing the address of the function, the function `std::unique` uses it by passing it two characters. And `erase` is overloaded for a few different argument types, one of which is a pair of iterators.

Comment: `it just came to me suddenly` [to me as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5561251/273767)!

Comment: @Cubbi: I should have known you'd have thought of it first.  The only guy I trust with C++ answers on Yahoo Answers. (I'm the user 'oops' by the way.)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I moved some of the code over into a class and now when I run it I get this error: http://i40.tinypic.com/2ynj8k4.png

Comment: @Seth: *"all the characters end up at the end of the string"* <-- Common myth.  Neither `std::unique` nor `std::remove` are required to do this, and I'm not aware of any implementation where they do.  They just copy or move the non-duplicate elements from the end toward the front.

Comment: @user386911: I'll need to see your code.  But the comments is perhaps not the best place for this.  Try to debug it yourself, then if you can't figure it out, make a new post.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley congrats on your gold badge

Answer (score 6):

So, I tried a way with std::remove_if & lambda expressions - though it seems still in my eyes easier to follow than above code, it doesn't have that "wow neat, didn't realize you could do that" thing to it.. Anyways I still post it, if only for learning purposes:

```
bool prev(false);
char rem(' ');
auto iter = std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&] (char c) -> bool {
    if (c == rem && prev) {
        return true;
    }
    prev = (c == rem);
    return false;
});
in.erase(iter, in.end());
```

**EDIT** realized that std::remove_if returns an iterator which can be used.. removed unnecessary code.

Comment: str.erase(iter, str.end()); instead of in.erase(iter, in.end());

Answer (score 4):

A variant of Benjamin Lindley's answer that uses a lambda expression to make things cleaner:

```
std::string::iterator new_end = 
        std::unique(str.begin(), str.end(),
        [=](char lhs, char rhs){ return (lhs == rhs) && (lhs == ' '); }
        );
str.erase(new_end, str.end());
```

Comment: getting [=] is useless, just use []

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a regular expression:

`boost::regex_replace(str, boost::regex("[' ']{2,}"), " ");`

Comment: C++11 also includes the `regex` library, which can be used if using boost is an issue.

Comment: There's no good reason, other than its just more fun to do algorithm jujitsu.

Comment: boost isnt part of the standard library is it?

Comment: @OwolabiEzekielTobiloba no it is not.

Answer (score 1):

how about `isspace(lhs) && isspace(rhs)` to handle all types of whitespace

Comment: Please answer after you try it on your own and with a sample working code