# a programm which removes excess spaces from a string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote a program which is supposed to remove excess spaces from a string. But it only shows characters before spaces. It finds a space and checks the character after that whether it is a space. Depending on excess spaces it shifts other characters over excess spaces. But output is very confusing.

input: "qwe(2 spaces)rt(one space)y"

output: "qwe(one space)rt(one space)y"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    int len = a.length();
    int new_len=len;
    int z,s=0;
    for(int i=0; i<new_len; i++){
        if(a[i]==' '){
            z=i+1;
            s=0;
            //Assigning the number of excess spaces to s.
            while(a[z]==' '){
                s++;
                z++;
            }
            //doing the shifting here.
            if(s>0){
                for(int l=i+1; l<new_len-s; l++){
                    a[l]=a[s+l];
                }
            }
            new_len-=s;
        }

    }
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << a.length();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362094/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one-space-in-a-string

Comment: I would consult [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and consider doing it a little more efficiently using `find_first_of()` and `find_first_not_of()` and their simulars.

Comment: `std::string a; cin >> a;` skips leading whitespace and only reads data into `a` until it hits more whitespace (which isn't read into `a`) or end-of-file, so you can't possibly have input with any whitespace to strip.  If you'd put `cout << "a '" << a << "'\n";` into your program you'd have noticed: such "trace" output is an essential diagnostic for programming, and would let you watch your program work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code is semi-pointless -- when you use the normal string extractor (`stream >> string`) it automatically skips across all consecutive leading white-space, and stops reading at the first whitespace character. As such, it's already doing almost everything the rest of your code is intended to accomplish. That leaves a much simpler approach to accomplishing the same task:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

This does have one problem: it'll leave one extra space at the *end* of the output. If you don't want that, you can use the [`infix_ostream_iterator`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489) I've posted previously. With that, you'd change the above to something like this:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. But it might be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is highly ineffective. Imagine a following string with 1,000,000 characters:

```
a  a  a  a  a  a  a...
```

Each time your algorithm encounters a second space, it goes through the whole string to shift it one char left. I would attempt another approach:

- Create two iterators, like realPos and charPos. Set them to 0 at the beginning.
- Create a variable, which stores a number of spaces encountered so far, like spacesSeen. Set it to 0.
- Now, while realPos is lower than length of the whole string:

  - If `string[realPos] != ' '` and `charPos != realPos`, make an assignment: `string[charPos] = string[realPos]`. Then increase both `realPos` and `charPos` by one. Set spacesSeen to 0.
  - If `string[realPos] == ' '` and `spacesSeen == 0`, increase `spacesSeen` by one, copy characters and advance both iterators.
  - If `string[realPos] == ' '` and `spacesSeen > 0`, then increase `spacesSeen` and then increase only `realPos`.
- Now charPos marks the place where your final string ends, adjust strings size, such that it ends there.

In simpler words: copy the characters one by one and skip multiple spaces on the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C++11 doing this your way is overkill - you can just use a regex. Something like the following should do it (untested):

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace::std;

int main(){
  string a;
  cin >> a;
  regex r(" +");
  a = regex_replace(a,r," ");
  cout << a << endl;
  cout << a.length();
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```