# How to remove all double spaces from string

Tags: c++, string

I am attempting to remove all double spaces from my string so that only single spaces remain:

```
while  (doublespace != -1) {
    kstring.replace(doublespace, 1, " ") ;
    doublespace = kstring.find_first_of("  ") ; }
```

it finds the first double space, triggering the while statement. It then takes the first space, adds 1 to it and sets the two spaces to one space. Then it checks again.

The problem is that the loop never ends - for example if I put "hello     " doubleSpace would never be set to -1.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `sString.replace(doubleSpace, 2, " ");` to replace *both* spaces?

Comment: That number could remove 100 spaces or 1 to remove 1 space, when the loop gets to one space left it does't set doubleSpace to -1

Comment: what if there is a triple space, after you removed a double space you end up with single space and single space which essentially a double space, should that be reduced to single space too?

Comment: But aren't you are only replacing one space with one space?

Comment: If I put "hello " the loop runs. The problem is the find_first_of line, it doesn't seem to recognise a single space as "not a double space"

Comment: @user690063 -- This can be accomplished on one line of code using `std::unique`, without the `for` loops.  If you're interested, I will post an answer using this technique.

Comment: @user690063 ok, I found [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362094/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one-space-in-a-string), with a [live example here using a lambda](https://www.ideone.com/VAQ9Cp). The lambda version is mine, but upvote Mr. Lindley if you like his answer.  Shows you the power of choosing the right algorithm.

Comment: @user690063 If a post answered your question, consider [marking it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6):

`std::string::find_first_of` only searches until it finds **one** of the characters in the input string, so as you pass it `"  "`, it'll effectively only search for `" "` - see the documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/):

> Searches the string for the first character that matches **any** of the characters specified in its arguments.

You should use [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) instead, which searches for the first instance of the entire substring:

> Notice that unlike member find_first_of, whenever more than one character is being searched for, it is not enough that just one of these characters match, but the entire sequence must match.

You're also replacing only the first space with a space (`sString.replace(doubleSpace, 1, " "`), which means your output will still contain double spaces. Just use [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) instead, to erase just the first space.

---

This means your code snippet should look more like:

```
std::size_t doubleSpace = sString.find("  ");
while (doubleSpace != std::string::npos)
{
    sString.erase(doubleSpace, 1);
    doubleSpace = sString.find("  ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the fix. find_first_of("+-/*") would give you the first location of ANY of the four operations in the string

Comment: As a potential for optimisation, would it be possible to use the iterator `sString.erase` returns to indicate to subsequent `find` calls where it is you'd like to resume your search from, and avoid reprocessing the parts which have already been processed? i.e. `iterator it = sString.erase(doubleSpace, 1); doubleSpace = sString.find("  ", it - sString.begin());`

Comment: @Sebivor Absolutely - that's what Galik's code does. I decided to stick to the OP's algorithm, as the question is about the behaviour they're encountering, not about efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative take that returns copy with only single spaces in it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = " hello   -    h e   l l    o   ";
    std::string newstr;

    size_t beg = 0;
    size_t len = str.length();

    while (beg < len)
    {
        size_t end = str.find_first_of(' ', beg) + 1;
        newstr += str.substr(beg, end - beg);
        beg = str.find_first_not_of(' ', end);
    }

    std::cout << newstr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

`hello - h e l l o`

As suggested by @hnefatl this approach could also be more efficient (see comment below)

Comment: You might want to mention that while this performs the exact same task as the OP's corrected code, it's more efficient (at first glance only `O(n)` rather than `O(n^2)` in `n` the length of `str`).

Answer (score 3):

I see two errors in your code. The first is that `find_first_of()` only searches for ***one*** of the characters you supply so, in your case, it will only be looking for single spaces. Secondly you only replace ***one*** space, not two.

This should fix both those problems:

```
std::string& reduce_double_spaces(std::string& s)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = s.find("  ");

    while (pos != std::string::npos) {

        // replace BOTH spaces with one space
        s.replace(pos, 2, " ");

        // start searching again, where you left off
        // rather than going back to the beginning
        pos = s.find("  ", pos);
    }

    return s;
}
```

**NOTE:** By beginning the subsequent searches from the place you found your last space, this version should be much more efficient. The longer the string the bigger the savings.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative uses const time operations of back(), pop_back(), push_back(), empty(), and size(),

```
std::string str = " hello   -    h e   l l    o   ";
std::string newStr = str;   // diag only

std::string Miss;    Miss.reserve(str.size());

while ( str.size() > 1 ) // note: str.back() undefined when str.empty()
{
   // fetch copy and          remove last element
   char aKar = str.back();    str.pop_back(); 

   if (! ((' ' == aKar)   &&    // space
         ( ' ' == str.back())))  // space
   {    
      Miss.push_back(aKar);  // not double-space 
   }
}
assert(1 == str.size()); // optional

while (! Miss.empty() )  // restore str to original order
{
   str.push_back (Miss.back()); // copy last element 
   Miss.pop_back();             // remove last element 
}
assert(Miss.empty()); // optional

std::cout << "\n  " << __FUNCTION__
          << "\n   in: " << newStr
          << "\n  out: " << str     << std::endl;
```