# Most efficient way of ignoring spacing on c++?

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

If I have two strings:

```
string str1 = "Something about the way that you walked into my living room";

string str2 = "Something about    the way that   you        walked into my  living room";
```

How do I write a function to return that these two strings are the same thing?

Comment: You can use two running indices, and jump to the next one if there are spaces

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Your comment can be easily read as snarky and condescending (and unwelcoming). While I somewhat sympathize with the temper (and the fact the you literally answer the question "How do I write a function..."), I don't think it was necessary to use that form. That question is actually quite nicely written (as in: easy to understand) and I imagine a number of people can find it helpful in future.

Comment: I would create two `std::istringstream` objects, one for each string, and then run a loop that reads substrings from each stream using `operator>>`, which ignores whitespace. If any given loop iteration returns different substrings, or one of the streams reaches EOF before the other, then the two strings are not equal.  Otherwise, if the loop ends cleanly, the two strings are equal.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of using `std::istringstream`, it would not be difficult to simply loop through both strings using `operator[]`, comparing characters while skipping whitespace.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. Not sure why it got put on hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can replace multiple consecutive spaces with single space as given here

[Replace multiple spaces with one space in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362094/)

Then compare the strings

Comment: "have to" implies that's the only way to compare strings ignoring spaces. It's not, and there are other more efficient ways

Comment: Agree, edited it to 'can'