# removing multiple spaces into one space to an output screen through emacs

Tags: c++, c++11, emacs

I am a beginner coder and I have looked up and researched on how I can remove multiple spaces to a single space but I did not understand what each algorithm was meant to do. I also tried to implement their algorithms into my program in emacs but all I received were errors when I debugged them.

I've looked into 
[Interview Question : Trim multiple consecutive spaces from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561138/interview-question-trim-multiple-consecutive-spaces-from-a-string) and
[Replace multiple spaces with one space in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362094/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one-space-in-a-string)
but I had no success.

The image shows what I am trying to do. Taking the spaces between cin and cout and converting them into one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5HaP.png)
I've already coded everything except the multiple spaces.

If anyone can clearly explain how I can do this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Using `regex` you can do: `std::regex_replace(some_string, std::regex("(\\s+)"), " ");`

Answer (score 0):

**1. The simplest solution using `string` methods:**

```
string str = "     many     spaces       ";
while(true)
{
    // find the starting position of two consecutive space characters
    unsigned int pos = str.find("  ");
    // if str.find does not find two consecutive spaces, it will return string::npos
    if(pos == string::npos) // no more consecutive spaces
    {
        break;
    }
    else // found two consecutive spaces
    {
        // erase one space
        str.erase(pos, 1);
    }
}
```

**2. The solution without using `string` methods (advanced):**

```
char charArray[] = "     many    spaces   ";
int write_index = 1;
if(sizeof(charArray) > 1) // the check starts at position 1 because we need to check if the previous character too (if it is a space)
{
    // repeat until the reading index reaches the end of the character array
    for(int read_index=1; read_index!=sizeof(charArray); ++read_index)
    {
        // if the current character or the previous character is not a space
        if(charArray[read_index] != ' ' || charArray[read_index-1] != ' ')
        {
            // then write the character
            charArray[write_index] = charArray[read_index];
            ++write_index;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `charArray` here must be a null-terminated character sequence, meaning the last character is `'\0'` or with an integral value of `0`. We are not erasing any characters from the end of the array after a part of the array has been overwritten. But we are copying the `0` character from the end to another position.
Example (N here marks the position of a null-character):

```
// array in the beginning:
"     many    spaces   N"
// after all replaces:
" many spaces Npaces   N"
```

Calling `cout` or constructing `string` types from the modified array will provide the desired result, because everything after the null-character will be clipped.
However, if you want to get completely rid of the characters in the array after the null-character, you must create a new array with the size of `write_index` and copy the characters from `charArray`.

How this method works was described in the "Interview Question" post's answer. I will explain a bit more:
We have two indices: `read_index` and `write_index`.
`read_index` is incremented in every iteration of the loop, it determines the character's position in the array which we are checking.
`write_index` is incremented only if a character is "saved", and by saving I mean overwriting a character which we have already checked earlier.

As you can see from the code, a character is "saved" only if it is not a space after another space. Therefore, whenever we find a space in the array, we will still save it, if the previous character was not a space. But if the previous character was also a space (and is, therefore, already saved), we skip it. As a result we will only have a maximum of one consecutive space in the ending array (only considering the characters before the first null-character, ofcourse).