# Need some help on a coding project

Tags: c++

I am a novice at coding and I am having quite a hard time at solving this problem. I'm not sure why it won't delete the extra white spaces.

```
void nospace(char line[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(line) / sizeof(line[0]); i++)
    {
        if (line[i-1] == ' ' && line[i] == ' ')
        {
            line[i-1] = line[i];
            line[i] = line[i+1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i` starts at 0, so `line[i-1]` is looking at index -1. That is a bad start...

Comment: I understand from your question, you wanted to trim multiple consecutive spaces from a string.
Have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561138/interview-question-trim-multiple-consecutive-spaces-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

```
void nospace(char *line)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    if (line[i] != ' ')
        line[count++] = line[i]; 
  line[count] = '\0';
}
```

Using Pointer will help to solve the problem For more information refer and try at

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-spaces-from-a-given-string/